# Use Boost Library Binary in Codelite

Tags: c++, boost, codelite

I'm new to boost and want to use it with Codelite.

I followed this guide here: [Official Boost Guide](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library)

Step 1) I installed it to `/usr/local/boost_1_67_0/`

Step 4) I can compile the example and it works as expected

Step 5) I just ran `./bootstrap.sh` and installed everything.
It succeeded and told me

```
>The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!
>
>The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:
>
>/usr/local/boost_1_67_0
>
>The following directory should be added to linker library paths:
>
>/usr/local/boost_1_67_0/stage/lib
```

So this is what I did in codelite:
[image: Codelite Compiler Settings]

[image: Codelite Linker Settings]

6) The example compiles errorlessly with codelite.

```
>g++  -c  "~/Dropbox/MasterThesis/C++/DiracTraceEvaluator/FeynCalc--/main.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall --std=c++11  -o ./Debug/main.cpp.o -I. -I. -I/usr/local/boost_1_67_0/
g++ -o ./Debug/FeynCalc-- @"FeynCalc--.txt" -L. -L./ -L/usr/local/boost_1_67_0/ -L/usr/local/boost_1_67_0/stage/lib/  -lboost_program_options -lboost_regex
```

Now if I execute the program, I get:

> ./FeynCalc--: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_regex.so.1.67.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I entered /usr/local/boost_1_67_0/stage/lib and all the required files are there. I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solve the issue was

creating a new file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`
I named it `boost.conf`

There I entered

```
# boost_1_67_0 default configuration
/usr/local/boost_1_67_0/stage/lib
```

Then I ran ldconfig in terminal.